# If gravity were to suddenly change, would the lift generated by a airfoil also change

Tags: forces, aerodynamics, lift

If gravity were to suddenly change, would the lift generated by a airfoil also change?

I realise that if gravity were to increase, then weight would also increase, leading to a change in the resultant force on the object (say a aeroplane). However, would the lift itself change, or just the resultant force.

I'm assuming it would due to possible change in fluid density, but am not sure.

If it were to change, would the opposite affect happen if gravity suddenly decreased?

Comment: The force required to lift the airfoil will decrease. The force needed is greater or equal to the weight of the airfoil with is dependent on the gravitational force. Decrease the force downwards and the force needed to lift upwards also decreases.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking [an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem we shall strict our calculations to incompressible flow, troposphere in atmosphere and standard ground temperature  is independent of gravity. Please note this is not true, modelling that is  difficult so this assumption is required to close this problem. This may give error in calculations but we shall get an overall picture.

Here we are considering two calculations one is, What will be the value of lift force at 10 $km$ altitude? and another is What would be the value of lift force at 10 $km$ altitude, if $g$ was 20 $N/m^2$? For that we need to calculate free steam at in those cases, so we briefly look about standard atmospheric calculations.

**International Standard Atmosphere**

Lets see how atmospheric values are calculated in troposphere.

Variation of pressure with height in troposphere is given by

$$P=P_0 \left (1-   \lambda \frac{h}{T_0} \right )^{\frac{g.M}{R.\lambda}}   $$

Here

$P_0$ is standard atmospheric pressure at sea level = 101327 $N/m^2$.

$\lambda$ is lapse rate = $ 6.5*10^{-3} K/m$

$h$ is height of altitude in meters

$g$ is acceleration due to gravity =9.8076 $m/s^2$

$M$ is molecular mass of air = 0.0289644 kg/mol

$R$ is  universal gas constant = 8.31432 $N.m. mol^{-1}·K^{-1}$

and Temperature is given by

$$T=T_0- \lambda h$$
Here,
$T_0$ is sea level temperature = 288.15 K

Temperature, pressure and density at 10 $Km$ is 223.15 $K$, 26437.3 $N.m^{-2}$ and 0.41271 $Kg/m^3$ respectively for real case.

Since its difficult to do real time calculations we are using dry adiabatic laps rate =$9.810^{-3}K/Km$ (this we shall cover in later section) for our calculation then the temperature, pressure and density at 10 $Km$ would be 190.15 $K$, 23779.17 $N.m^{-2}$ and 0.4355 $Kg/m^3$ respectively for real case.

**Let see what are the parameters of atmosphere will change if $g$ is a variable:**

Let say our $g$ is increased to 20 $m/s^2$ then it will affect $P_0$, $T_0$, $\rho_0$ but its very difficult to estimate or model those thing. We already assumed that $T_0$ is same as actual sea level temperature. But temperature may increase because all heavy and green house gases try to find there place next to earth crust, pressure and density is two times of actual value when gravity is doubled because weight of atmosphere is doubled.

Increasing $g$ value also change lapse rate ($\lambda$). Actual  $\lambda$ is Thermodynamic-based lapse rate. That formula is complicated and tedious to analyze so we strict our self to dry adiabatic lapse rate . Though adiabatic lapse rate value is $ 9.8*10^{-3} K/m $ more than actual one, it can be used to get overall picture about this process.

The adiabatic lapse rate is given approximately by :

$\lambda_w = g/c_p$

$\lambda_w$ = Dry adiabatic lapse rate, K/m

$g$= Earth's Standard gravity, gravitational acceleration= 9.8076$m/s^{2}$

$c_p$=The specific heat of dry air at constant pressure, = 1003.5 $JKg^{-1}K^{-1}$

$\lambda_w$ with $g$ = 20 $m/s^2$, is $19.93*10^-3 K/m$ assuming gas is calorically perfect.

Pressure temperature and density at 10 Km altitude with $g$ =20 $m/s^2$ is 3314.8 $N/m^2$, 88.67 $K$ and 0.1302 $kg/m^3$ receptively.

**Definition of lift is:**

When a fluid flowing passes the surface of a body exerts a force on it. Lift is the component of this force that is perpendicular to the oncoming flow direction. Please don't confuse this with resulting upward force opposite in direction to weight, that is different, lift is different.

Let see the formula for lift,

$$L=0.5*C_l*\rho*v^2*S$$

where
$L$ is the lift force,

$\rho$ is fluid density

$v$ is true airspeed

$S$ is platform area

$C_l$ is lift coefficient

here $C_l$ depends on Reynolds number and body shape; Reynolds number depends on free stream parameters like temperature, density etc. but variation of $C_l$ w.r.t Reynolds number is negligible. Since our body shape will not change, we shall assume $C_l$ is more or less a constant parameter and $C_l$ is independent of gravitational force. Here I'm assuming lift force acting opposite in direction to weight. Please not that in most of the practical applications this is not true.

Lets calculate lift force for those two cases:
Lets take $C_l$=1,$v$ =1, $S$ =1 and mass=1 $kg$;
For $g$ =9.81 $m/s^2$

Lift force is 0.21775 $N$, weight is 9.81 $N$ and resulting upward force is -9.59225 $N$

For case 2: $g$ =20 $m/s^2$

Lift force is 0.066, weight is 20 $N$ and resulting upward force is -19.934 $N$

**Answer:**

- At ground resulting upward force slightly reduces with increase in gravity but that is negligible.
- If $g$ is increased lift force will decrease with altitude
- lift force also decrease  increase in gravity . Lift force is a
  nonlinear function of $g$
- $C_l$ is almost constant; Because of increase in Reynolds number it will increase but that is negligible.
- Resulting upward force in airfoil will decrease if $g$ is increased because of reduction in lift and increase in body weight at some height.

(Please note that I made a big assumption that sea level temperature would not change with change w.r.t gravity)

Comment: `With g=9.98m/s2, density at 10 Km is 0.41271 Kg/m3` `With g=20 m/s2, density is 0.0651 kg/m3` This doesn't make sense. Why would the density decrease with an increase in gravity?

Comment: Please note that all the molecules try to say near earth so  density at upper layer (here 10 Km) will decrease, but that will increase the density at sea level that is difficult to calculate or model, so here I assumed sea level property would not change, to close the problem. If you consider the density ratio that is more than 6 times. I hope sea level density with $g$=20 $m/s^2$ can't be six times as actual density. Calculations here are exaggerated the values but the result may be valid.

Comment: @LDC3, I will try to make a mathematical model to find sea level density for different $g$, If you know any models pls. suggest me. Even if we frame one mathematical model, setting boundary conditions are highly uncertain and those b.C are asymptotic in nature may lead to wrong marching values in numerical methods!

Comment: Consider a cube of air with a volume of 1 mL, if the gravity is doubled, then the weight of the cube would double, causing the pressure under it to double. This would decrease the volume of air under it by half. In effect doubling the density of the air. This would decrease the air column by half, but an increase in gravity would pull a taller air column, so the density would be even greater. So at g=9.98m/s2, the density at 10 Km is 0.41271 Kg/m3, it would be greater than double that when g=20m/s2. You can calculate the lift at this density for a start.

Comment: @LDC3, Sir, I'm agreeing with you, but factors you consider here is ideal, I could have used sea level pressure =2*actual pressure that makes little sense. That will not affects my conclusion that affects only my calculations. Modelling temperature at sea level need lot of calculations like, thermal energy absorption of gases, heat released by space object, heat reflected by  earth and so on... Please go through this link, to get a overall idea to  how ISA formula is formed. <home.anadolu.edu.tr/~mcavcar/common/ISAweb.pdf>

Comment: The OP is asking about an impossible condition, so a rough calculation is all that is needed.

Comment: I answered this question to get an overall idea about how to solve this problem. I made lot of assumptions among them invalid assumption is i took sea level parameters are independent of gravity. I mentioned that thing in after answer section. This problem has less physical significance.

Comment: @LDC3 If we develop one good mathematical model to calculate sea level parameters that can be used to study planets atmosphere from earth!. That can become one example problem in mathematical model course but may have less application in reality. We prefer elector magnetic spectrum of light emitted by planet to determine its temperature

Comment: I don't think a good model could be made. Venus is slightly smaller than Earth, but has a much denser atmosphere. Along with planet size and distance from the sun, the solar wind, magnetic field and meteoroids determine how much atmosphere a planet can retain. There may be a few other factors I missed. We barely know the history of the formation of the Earth and Venus. We wouldn't be able to determine the history of formation of an exoplanet for some time (probably not without visiting it).

Comment: @LDC3, What you told is right. As you told we can approximately determine pressure but temperature model is tough. I only answered this question to get an overall ideal to this process, the complexity and uncertainty in the process. This may be wrong if my assumptions failed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed mathematical model. So many assumptions always need to be made when modelling aerodynamics!

Comment: @JAS what you told is true. As you have noticed, peoples here, hate hypothetical questions but hypothetical questions improve thinking. You could have asked what will be effect of airfoil of a spaceship if that is flying in Jupiter and earth (or polar region and equator). You didn't asked about aircraft,that is more complicated because, maneuverability, stability, aerodynamics, propulsion etc. of the aircraft depends on free-steam parameter and $g$

Answer (score 2):

If gravity changes, then so will the density of air. Air pressure at the surface is  proportional to the weight of the column of air above it, so if gravity increases, the pressure would, too. That will in turn affect the lift from an airfoil. [NASA says lift varies linearly with density.](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/density.html)  I suspect the two effects would pretty much balance each other.

Answer (score 1):

If gravity increases, so does air density and pressure, but also air temperature. Since density decreases with increasing temperature, the increase in density will not be sufficient to fully compensate for the increased weight of the aeroplane.

The aeroplane will begin to sink, which in turn will increase its angle of attack. Consequently, it will settle at a new flow condition where lift equals weight, given that it had enough speed initially so the increased angle of attack does not stall it.

If you look at the long-term equilibrium at the new gravity, the air should cool down again to a temperature close to the initial conditions. Then the density increase is proportional with the gravity increase, and at the same flow conditions, the aeroplane will create just enough lift to support its increased weight.

Comment: Interesting approach, looking at how lift will adapt to a new equilibrium. I was thinking more of immediate affect, but this was also very informative and helpful